# How get cookies in use (allowed) in page? Javascript

Tags: javascript

how get cookies allowed, those that are shown in the "lock" of the browser?

I get a redirect in my page and I need to get a certain SESSION_ID that is passed through certain layers of the API...

Several articles and answers show how to get it from the browser's storage but this type of cookie is not saved there... An example image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pjcP.png

Comment: Not all cookies are accessible through JS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

### Read a Cookie with JavaScript

With JavaScript, cookies can be read like this:

```js
let x = document.cookie;
```

### Some nice functions

Get a Cookie

```js
function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Set a Cookie

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Comment: if this doesnt work, then look up `localStorage` api